# What would happen if you "forgot to click Finish" after installing drivers successfully?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, chipset

Im curious as to what happens when you dont click "Finish" after a driver install and just restart pc ofc you installed the drivers successfully but what's gonna happen when you just reboot and "forgot to click finish" Would the PC reboot and close off the process and consider it as Finished?

It wouldnt corrupt the driver no?
If yes then is it still possible to delete such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the driver installation. Most installations
would prepare all the parameters and only execute when the
finishing button is pressed.

The likely result is then that nothing will change and the
old driver will stay.
At most you would have some files left around that the
installation did not have the opportunity to clean up.
Running the installation again will remove them when finished
(or when cancelled by using the Cancel button).

Of course, there may exist badly-written installations for
which this logic does not apply.

Comment: Since its a clean install for example no driver would be installed?

Comment: Yes, this is the most likely result.

Comment: Noted, noted. So that would mean that the said driver wont show up in the Control Panel because the driver wasnt installed properly and should show a warning sign in Device Manager correct?

Comment: Was it showing up correctly before you ran the aborted installation? Could you add details about the driver and hardware?

Comment: @s0utt Are you just asking out of curiosity?  Or do you have a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Im asking out of curiousity and too trying to see what happens if it happens because maybe i did something wrong? during the installation process

Comment: Because i was nervous if wether or not i clicked "Finish" though i just probably forgot about it because i was distracted at my phone and i probably did it out of insticnt and not me noticing that i pressed it. And so i didnt remember it vividly but i can recall after the installation process i clicked Finish? and through all my recollection i could not remember if there was a window that asked me to click Finish and so i went panic mode 

Comment: The simplest solution would be to run the installation again to the finish.

Comment: It was a chipset driver would that make a difference? or should i just uninstall and reinstall. though everything is functioning as normal

Comment: I just uninstalled the driver and about to reinstall it again.

Comment: Reinstalled without any issue.

Comment: Oh and also is that normal if the setup file was large like 9.80 mb and the Chipset Software were just 2.86 mb?

Comment: Depends on the installation. Some contain more than one version of the driver for multiple possible setups.

Comment: But considering that my system works just fine before i did the uninstall/reinstall everything should be all fine no?

Comment: just incase im doing sfc /scannow and DISM. 

Comment: Everything's fine i suppose i got the right piece of mind after uninstalling and reinstalling the driver and remembering that i clicked finish this time  everything should be clean